# Is there a build of Blender that only has the video editor enabled?

Tags: versions, video-sequence-editor

Seeing as the video editor has become as powerful as it is, it would be great to use it as a stand alone video editor.

Does such a build exist?

Comment: Keep in mind that apart from the game engine, the other parts of Blender are tied closely together. I don't think it is possible to have such a build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Short, No.
You can make blender builds without many features (collada, game-engine, freestyle, smoke etc). But you can't make a video only version of Blender.

Comment: What you could do is provide a startup.blend that has only screen layouts geared towards video editing, but the user still could access all the other parts.

Answer (score 6):

I'm almost completely sure there are no builds with just the video editor, but if you wanted to use it primarily as a video editor, you could set the video editor as the default view when blender is loaded up.